# 3D Dot Game Heroes Hero Blueprints

Tags: 3d-dot-game-heroes

3D Dot Game Heroes lets you build your own 3D Dot Hero -- but let's face it, the average individual, such as myself, are not that great at 3-d pixel art.

Is there a database of 3d dot heroes with blueprints on how to craft them, in game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official website](http://www.3ddotgameheroes.com/hallofheroes/) has a large DB of user created heroes, and you can copy them over to your machine using a USB memory stick.